# What is the difference between AWS Pinpoint and AWS SNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-pinpoint

I am new to Push Notification and really interested in it. We have AWS SNS (Simple Push Notification) and AWS Pinpoint.

I am confuse about these services from AWS.

1. What is the difference between them?
2. If I want to send push notification to my phone, which one should I
   use?

If you have any ideas, please let me know.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: You can think of them as SNS being low-level messaging system, where you have to code a lot of behavior. Pinpoint is high level, and provides you with out-of-the-box common functionality (e.g. scheduling messages, message templates, etc).

Answer (score 13):

> Q. If I want to send push notification to my phone, which one should I use?
>
> A. Both Amazon SNS and Amazon Pinpoint, support push notification feature and I normally like classifying them as *"Mobile Push Messaging"* tools however they differ in mechanism as discussed below.

The major difference between Amazon SNS & Amazon Pinpoint is addressed by the [Pinpoint FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/faqs/)

> Q: I already use Amazon SNS or Amazon SES. What do I gain by switching
> to Amazon Pinpoint?
>
> In typical Amazon SNS and Amazon SES use cases, you have to set up
> your application to manage each message's audience, content, and
> delivery schedule. These same features are built in to Amazon
> Pinpoint. With Amazon Pinpoint, you can create message templates,
> delivery schedules, highly-targeted segments, and full campaigns.

Some of the key features offered by Amazon Pinpoint *(i.e currently not offered by Amazon SNS)* are:

- Supports [two-way messaging](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/two-way-sms-with-amazon-pinpoint/)
- Understand User Behavior
- Supports [voice messages](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/amazon-pinpoint-now-enables-customers-to-deliver-voice-messages-to-their-users-in-over-200-countries/)
- Create Targeted Campaigns
- Supports [.p8 token authentication](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/09/amazon-pinpoint-broadens-reach-of-multi-channel-messaging-with-new-support-for-amazon-device-messaging-baidu-cloud-push-and-apns-sandbox-and-p8-token-authentication-for-apns/) for APNs
- Measure Results

Hope this helps

Comment: Just wanted to add that SNS supports token based authentication since 2021 as well https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/11/amazon-sns-token-authentication-api-mobile-notifications/